# How well will a machine rated for 120 volts 60 hz work with 120 volts 50 hz?

Tags: electrical, appliances, transformer

Moving oversea wanting to know how well my Zaaz Vibration Platform Fitness Machine will work with a transformer that will step down 220 volts to 120 volts with 50hz?

Comment: Is there a motor in it?

Comment: If it is [this one](https://zaazmovement.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ZAAZ-20K-User-Manual_WEB1.pdf) in addition to the 50/60 Hz issue, I would be concerned with *The machine is not compatible with GFCI-equipped outlets and may not be compatible with AFCI-equipped outlets*.